# Encrypt/decrypt binary file in Perl using blowfish or AES?

Tags: perl, aes, blowfish

I'm trying to encrypt and then decrypt a binary file in Perl without success, the decrypted file always differs from the original. I tried both Blowfish and AES (Rijandael), here is a short example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Crypt::CBC;
use autodie;

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key    => 'my secret key',
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -header => 'none',
    -iv     => 'dupajasi'
);
$cipher->start('encrypting');
my $sourcefile = "fs9419105v001s.zip";

{
    open(my $OUTF, '>', "$sourcefile.perl.crypt");
    open(my $F, '<', $sourcefile);
    print "[?] Encrypting ... \n";
    while (read($F, $buffer, 1024)) {
        print $OUTF $cipher->crypt($buffer);
    }
    print {$OUTF} $cipher->finish;
    close($OUTF);
}

print "[?] Decrypting.,..... \n";
$cipher2 = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key    => 'my secret key',
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -header => 'none',
    -iv     => 'dupajasi'
);

{
    open(my $OUTF, '>', "$sourcefile.perl.decrypt");
    open(my $F, '<', "$sourcefile.perl.crypt");
    while (read($F, $buffer, 1024)) {
        print {$OUTF} $cipher2->decrypt($buffer);
    }
    print {$OUTF} $cipher2->finish;
    close($OUTF);
}
```

Can someone help me find out what is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I decrypt AES-generated crypttext in PHP with Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334843/how-do-i-decrypt-aes-generated-crypttext-in-php-with-perl)

Comment: no, it is not a dupe. That one is AES interoperability with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm this. I found a hint: the difference occurs exactly at the 1024<sub>10</sub>/400<sub>16</sub> boundary.

```
> diff -u fs9419105v001s.zip.hex fs9419105v001s.zip.perl.decrypt.hex
--- fs9419105v001s.zip.hex
+++ fs9419105v001s.zip.perl.decrypt.hex
@@ -62,7 +62,7 @@
 03d0  5d d9 f2 f6 43 bb 3d 9d  92 aa 89 ca 75 dc 0e 51  ]...C.=. ....u..Q
 03e0  55 b2 1a e8 65 d5 29 ac  ca d9 a4 f8 1a cc 67 8b  U...e.). ......g.
 03f0  f9 1b 65 be bc 19 bf 51  e6 9f de 28 ef db db ff  ..e....Q ...(....
-0400  85 38 78 09 a7 62 9f 9d  08 db fc cb 13 90 b9 84  .8x..b.. ........
+0400  c6 a0 8b 75 f4 17 6b 64  08 db fc cb 13 90 b9 84  ...u..kd ........
 0410  f4 a8 30 d2 1d 19 52 f7  8e 84 09 a8 59 f3 4e 1e  ..0...R. ....Y.N.
 0420  3c 30 ca 6e 5b dc bb f3  48 fa 5d 3c b1 e0 64 07  <0.n[... H.]<..d.
 0430  61 98 9e a1 57 9a 69 d6  35 a7 95 5b 0d d7 31 c4  a...W.i. 5..[..1.
```

This is more a comment than an answer, but unfortunately the comment box is not suitable for this reply.

Comment: That may differ by input file, so isn't very useful without it.

Comment: You are wrong. The difference occurs is always at the exact boundary of multiples of 400(hex), no matter what file encrypted. Does it hurt to take two minutes to test your hypothesis before you make a fool of yourself?

Comment: I'm seeing this, as well; every 1024 bytes there are 8 bytes that are different. (Perl 5.8.8, Crypt::CBC 2.24.)

Comment: It appears to be every multiple of the buffer size passed to `read()` in the decryption loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should call `binmode`
2. You have missed
   `->start('decrypting');` on decrypt.
3. You should use `crypt()` not `decrypt()`. [ yes, this is confusing ] see perldoc:

> decrypt()
>
> > `$plaintext = $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext)`
>
> This
>   convenience function runs the entire
>   sequence of start(), crypt() and
>   finish() for you, processing the
>   provided ciphertext and returning the
>   corresponding plaintext.

The decryption routine should look like this:

```
$cipher2 = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key    => 'my secret key',
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -header => 'none',
    -iv     => 'dupajasi'
);

$cipher2->start('de')

print "[?] Decrypting ... \n";

{
    open(my $OUTF, '>', "$sourcefile");
    open(my $F, '<', "$sourcefile.perl.crypt");
    binmode $OUTF;
    binmode $F;
    while (read($F, $buffer, 1024)) {
        print $OUTF $cipher2->crypt($buffer);
    }
    print $OUTF $cipher2->finish;
    close $OUTF;
}
```

Comment: binmode is advised, but the lack of it here is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @daxim, i believe `binmode` is the cause. if you have other idea in mind, why don't you answer this?

Comment: I had this hypothesis, too, but compared to you I was not lazy and took the two minutes to verify it. Beliefs belong into the temple, programming has no place for it.